# Mount SMB Share on macOS from Terminal having a @ in Password

Tags: macos, shell, command, smb

I know how to mount a SMB Share from macOS.

Looks like this

```
/sbin/mount -t smbfs //WORKGROUP;User:Password@Server/Folder$ ~/Desktop/Mount
```

But, what if my Password had an `@` in it? This is not working in my case.

I tried to set an Backslash in front of the `@`  like `\@`, nothing happened. Could also be the same problem when using an @ in username, I think.

Any ideas?

BR